# Correct way to increment value for JavaScript function call

Tags: javascript

The following code works fine:

```
$(document).on('click', "input[id='inputfield0']",
   function() {
      myFunction(0); 
});

$(document).on('click', "input[id='inputfield1']",
   function() {
      myFunction(1); 
});

$(document).on('click', "input[id='inputfield2']",
  function() {
     myFunction(2); 
})
```

I want to remove the repetition, as follows:.

```
 function oneCall() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
       $(document).on('click', "input[id='inputfield"+i+"']",
          function() {
             myFunction(i); 
          });
    }
 }

function oneCall();
```

However, in the new function `oneCall()`, each time `myFunction()` is called within the loop, it is being passed a value of 2, rather than being incremented on each call. 
What is the correct way to restructure this code?

Thanks

Comment: Add a class to each input and add the listener on said class.

Comment: change `var` to `let`. Don't use `var` anymore.

Comment: yes - changing 'var' to 'let' solved to issue. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Add a class to each input and add the listener on said class.

```js
function myFunction(v) {
  console.log(v);
}

$('.click-listener').on('click', function(e) {
  let $target = $(e.target),
      id = parseInt($target.attr('id').split('-')[1], 10);
  myFunction(id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="inputfield-0" class="click-listener" />
<input id="inputfield-1" class="click-listener" />
<input id="inputfield-2" class="click-listener" />
```